# Why does django only allows access to the widget attributes when it renders a field into a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a question about Django template rendering. Right now I use it to build a full-stack app, so the issue is that when I try to override a default form rendering behavior, I see that despite I can possibly overwrite default html without boilerplate, it is becoming harder as I dive deeper.

Let's take a look on the excerpt from [table.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/templates/django/forms/table.html) which renders form as table.

```
...

{{ field }}
{% if field.help_text %}
  <br>
  <span class="helptext"{% if field.auto_id %} id="{{ field.auto_id }}_helptext"{% endif %}>{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>

...
```

Here we see that every form Field will render like

```
<label>
~<input>
<span> (help_text)
```

But what if we want to overwrite default Field(e.g. ImageField) rendering behaviour to produce html portion like the below code to be able to add a preview avatar before the <input>-<help text> combination.

```
<div>
  <img>(preview)
  <div>
    <input>
    <span>{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

We can't just write custom html for our field, like django/forms/widgets/text.html, because it only has Widget in the context.

**So without boilerplate it is straightforward to overwrite how <input> tag is rendered using custom html files, but it is not straightforward how to make custom <label> and help_text rendering on per-field-class basis. Seems like we are stuck with either writing a lot of if-else statements or doing some inheritance.**

From my point of view Field should encapsulate rendering of label and helptext, but for some reason it is only about <input> tag.

I have investigated the sources, only to find out django only allows an access to a Widget in the default rendering mechanism. I want to be able to override full  portions on per-Field basis ideally by changing some config, or writing a single class, e.g. some template renderer, and setting it to be the default one with some configuration value.